# Loki summing up the parsed value from two different application

Tags: grafana-loki, logql

I have two applications printing the logs, the message ID is same in both the app logs. I have the extract the the processing time and sum both the time and get the value as 1050.

**Logs:**

app1:

```
Record id:xxxxx-0 :: Message id:**xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-1** total processing time :: 30
Record id:xxxxx-0 :: Message id:**xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-2** total processing time :: 20
```

app2:

```
Record id:xxxxx-0 :: Message id:**xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-1** total processing time :: 1020
Record id:xxxxx-0 :: Message id:**xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-2** total processing time :: 40
```

**Query Used:**

```
sum by(message_id) (sum_over_time({app=~"bulkconsumer|carterconsumer"} 
| regexp `Record id:(?P<record_id>\d+-\d+) :: Message id:(?P<message_id>.*?) total processing time :: (?P<processing_time>\d+)` 
| unwrap processing_time 
| __error__=`` [$__range]))
```

**Expected Result:**

Need to find out the processing time for each message id and then calculate the average processing time

Message id 1: processing time 1050
Message id 2: processing time 60

The average processing time is average of processing time 1 and processing time 2

**Result:**

I am able to extract the fields using Regex. But the message id is not sum up, it is showing twice.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzR3X.png)

But I want the aggregated sum only where it is coming in the middle and the first and last data point consist of the processing time 1 and processing time 2 from both apps for same message id

Comment: Graph shown on screenshot doesn't correspond to sample data and query. There should be tow lines: one for each message id. Could you re-check that, please?